# Fargate cross account DynamoDB access

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-fargate, sts-securitytokenservice

I have DynamoDB in account A and Fargate service in account B. I want to access the DynamoDB from Fargate service. For this,
1. Created an IAM role in account A that has the policy attached for DynamoDB access.
2. Created an IAM role in account B that is attached to a policy that assumes role created in account A.
3. Added account B ID in the trusted relationship of account A.

In the code for creating DynamoDBClient, used `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` by passing the ARN of role created in account A. When running the service, getting an Access Denied error.

`User: <ARN of ECS task> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: <ARN of role created in account A> (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;`

ARN of ECS task is of format `arn:aws:sts::<accountId of B>:assumed-role/<ECSTaskInstanceID>`. 
Please note `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` is added to trusted relation in account B with action of sts:AssumeRole.

1. Is STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider supported in Fargate?
2. Is there any additional step required like AWS access key creation?
3. Any reason for 403?

Comment: Did you attach the IAM role created in account B (which has permission to assume the IAM role in account A) as the task role for ECS service ?

Comment: @Jeevagan, IAM role is not attached to the task. Any references to attach IAM role to a task via console?

Comment: You need to create a new version of task definition with task role and update the service. 
In this link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html, check the step 3 under Fargate launch type.

Comment: Thanks Jeevagan. I created a new task definition version and added the task role created in account B. Updated the service to ensure it takes the latest version. Still getting the same error 403, AccessDenied

Comment: Can you share the trust policy of IAM role in account A and IAM policy of role in account B ?